# How to bypass login requirement to scrape facebook public page

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Facebook public pages (pages that are available to the public), and I managed to build a scraper using beautiful soup.

However I noticed that it does not work after several attempts because Facebook gives message that I need to log in.

Is there a way to by pass the login requirement?

For example, a public page as a unique identifier and it would turn into login address:

```
https://facebook.com/seouljake

https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fseouljake
```

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried using Facebook api - https://pypi.org/project/python-facebook-api/

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API.